# BeyondCompare3 - How to see exact differences of multiple files at once?

Tags: beyondcompare, beyondcompare3

I just got Beyond Compare 3 and I'm having a hard time finding the exact differences for multiple files in 2 folders.

If I use File Compare to find differences between 2 files it tells me exactly where the differences are. This is what I want but if I have hundreds of files in each folder, I don't want to click through each file pair. Folder compare only tells me that differences exists without showing me where they are in each file.

I don't know the first thing about scripting but is there a feature to automate File Compare's results and produce a report with all the differences per pair?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

After loading the parent folders in the folder compare, use either the **Actions > Compare Contents** menu item, or the **Session Settings** dialog's **Compare Contents** option to start a comparison of all of the files.  The first is a distinct one-off action; the second will run and update automatically whenever the files change.

Once that's done, double click on the top pair of files with differences to view them in the file compare.  When the file compare has been launched from a folder compare you can then use **Search > Next Difference Files** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>) and **Search > Previous Difference Files** (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>) to move between the different pairs of files without closing it or switching back to the parent folder compare.

If you want a flat list of all of the differences across all of the files, you can select the files in the folder compare and use the **Actions > File Comparison Report...** command to generate a printed or HTML dump of everything.  It's intended has a hard copy, not for interactive use, but it's available if you need it.